# angular material mat-button loses styling when I use [className]

Tags: angular-material2

I need to add a custom class to my mat-buttons.  This class will be used by an automated testing tool.  But when I add [className]="QA_myclass", I lose all material styling.  How can get around this?  Anyone know?

Comment: Please share a complete code example.

Comment: So I fixed this by using [ngClass]

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here.  Use [ngClass] instead of [className].